# How to prevent plotly from adding the wrong label (via bar.update_traces()) to my barplot if I use the color option (px.bar())?

Tags: python, plotly

New to plotly and going crazy trying to solve this issue. I can color code my data by the value of the 'Generation' column below. I can add the value of my 'Round_Emax' column above the bars. However, I can't do both at the same time.

It seems like when I specify the color in px.bar(color='Generation) and then try to use px.bar.update_traces(texttemplate=round_emax_data) to add the values, it causes the index of round_emax_data to reset, adding the incorrect label. However, I don't know how to work around this. I feel like the 'update' term is a clue that it is changing the underlying data, but I haven't been able to figure out how to add what I need in the original px.bar() function call. I've tried the 'hover_data' option but that didn't work.

Here is the construction of the data:

```
#for stackoverflow
#imports
import pandas as pd
import plotly.express as px
import plotly.graph_objects as go

#data

emax_SO = [233, 238, 241, 259, 267, 275, 281, 300, 293, 282, 271, 278, 
            'XXX', 88]
gen = ['Gen1', 'Gen1', 'Gen1', 'Gen1', 'Gen1', 
       'Gen2', 'Gen2', 'Gen2', 'Gen2','Gen2', 'Gen2', 'Gen2',
      'Lit', 'Gen0']
emax_data = [0.0476, 0.0743, 0.0492, 0.0663, 0.0427, 0.0606, 0.0815, 
             0.0706, 0.0338, 0.0156, 0.0696, 0.0331, 0.0, 0.0]
round_emax_data = [round(x, 3) for x in emax_data]


#construct df
df = pd.DataFrame(emax_mol, dtype=str)
df.columns=['MoleculeID']
df['Generation'] = gen
df['Emax'] = emax_data
df['Round_Emax'] = round_emax_data
```

Plot with desired bar chart labels, no coloring:

```
fig=px.bar(df, 
           y = 'Round_Emax', 
           x='MoleculeID', 
           #color='Generation',
          )
fig.update_traces(texttemplate=round_emax_data, 
                  textposition='outside')
fig.update_layout(yaxis_title='EMax', 
                  title = 'Arbitrary Title')
fig.show()
```

[Values above bar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/850yz.png)

Plot with corect coloring, no bar values:

```
fig=px.bar(df, 
           y = 'Round_Emax', 
           x='MoleculeID', 
           color='Generation',
          )
fig.update_traces(#texttemplate=round_emax_data, 
                  #textposition='outside'
)
fig.update_layout(yaxis_title='EMax', 
                  title = 'Arbitrary Title')
fig.show()
```

[Colors by 'Generation' label](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OegbP.png)

trying to do both

```
fig=px.bar(df, 
           y = 'Round_Emax', 
           x='MoleculeID', 
           color='Generation',
          )
fig.update_traces(texttemplate=round_emax_data, 
                  textposition='outside'
)
fig.update_layout(yaxis_title='EMax', 
                  title = 'Arbitrary Title')
fig.show()
```

[weird behavior when i try to do both](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zXGZ8.png)

As you can see, the values for Gen2, Lit and Gen0 are wrong. But the values for Gen1 are correct. Can anyone help? Or an example where someone has done both of these things?

In plotly's example they use this line:

fig.update_traces(texttemplate='%{text:.2s}', textposition='outside')

in an example to put the values on top of the columns (but they do not color by a legend), but I don't understand this notation '%{text:.2s}'. Maybe I have to do something like this? But I can't figure out how to adapt it to my dataframe. I hope this isn't a bad question, I am trying.

Answer (score 0):

The most basic addition of a label is to set a text item and then add a setting for automatic text display. px.bar does not allow setting the display position of the label, so the label position is set in the graph update. In this example, some of the text is cut off, so change the y-axis limit. The format for label notation is in D3 format, see [here](https://github.com/d3/d3-3.x-api-reference/blob/master/Formatting.md#d3_forma).

The cause of the labeling is unknown, but it appears that the y-axis values are annotated in the category units due to the age categories in the colors.

```
fig = px.bar(df, 
             y = 'Round_Emax', 
             x = 'MoleculeID', 
             color = 'Generation',
             text = 'Round_Emax',
             text_auto='.2%'
          )
fig.update_traces(textposition='outside')
fig.update_yaxes(range=[0, 0.1])
fig.show()
```

[image]